# Name for something that can "Target"

Tags: nouns

So I am trying to name some interfaces in my code, and I can't seem to find an appropriate name for one of them.

I have Target for the Enemy, what would the thing "Targeting" it. It is not shooting it, it could be a sniper, a tank, a missile etc.

What would you call something that can target an object?

An answer on here suggests "Aimer" but that does not feel right at all, "Targeter" is not even a word, or at least not according to a Dictionary.

Any ideas?

First post here so excuse my terrible grammar and structure :p.

Comment: Something that can "target" the enemy is usually called a ***weapon***.

Comment: Does the dictionary you cite have an entry '_target_ is not a word'? Wiktionary has the agent noun  **targeter** 
n. A person who selects targets (typically for a remote weapons system). Some dictionaries list more words than others.

Comment: Other than shooter, gunner, archer/bowman I don't see what can fit your context.

Comment: Tracker or Tracking Reticle might work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming code artifacts, not English per se. That practice is specifically prohibited per the faq.

Comment: See what's [on topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tracker**.

Point your **tracker** at a target and it will track it - keep it in its sights - for as long as you need.  The term is used this way commonly enough in computer games to be relevant, if nothing else.

**Trace** or **tracer** *might* be alternatives but I think **tracker** is 
clearer.  Of the two, I prefer **trace**.  It has a fine pedigree, both from traditional hunting and modern day surveillance, without the potential confusion that **tracer** presents since it can mean a kind of ammunition.

**Pointer**, while being the name of a type of hunting dog, is terribly inappropriate given the context ;)

Comment: This is good, Tracker is a very good name for it. As technically it keeps "track" of where a target is

Answer (score 0):

"Forward **sensors** have a target lock Captain."

"Fire as you will Mr. Sulu!"

In infrared homing ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_lock-on#Infrared_homing)):

> In this scenario, the target itself provides the (infrared) emissions that the missile's Infrared homing sensor is able to detect; lock-on occurs when the missile is powered up and able to "see" the infrared signature of the target.

Comment: Also a very good answer for what I need, technically speaking this actually fits for my purpose (as is) more than the above, however as I expand the code it will make less and less sense.